# What's a good program to record video or screencast being played on screen?

Tags: video, screen-recording

What's a good program to record videos or screencasts being played on screen?

Comment: Lot more info in a previous question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763/tips-on-recording-a-webcast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763/tips-on-recording-a-webcast)

Comment: Shouldn't this go to superuser or programming?

Answer (score 5):

I've had success with Camtasia / CamStudio.  Check out http://showmedo.com for tutorials.  It's a little recursive though - it would be better to capture it from source.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, you have [CamTasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.asp) (commercial), [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) (GPL), [FRAPS](http://www.fraps.com/) (commercial with free trial).

FRAPS will definitely do your job, it was designed to capture videos of 3D games.  CamTasia might, it has a low-level custom codec (TechSmith Capture Codec).  CamStudio probably won't, at least not smoothly.  CamStudio has issues on Vista, I don't know about FRAPS, CamTasia is fine on Vista.

On the Mac try ScreenFlow, their [example video](http://www.flip4mac.com/screenflow.htm) makes it clear it can capture live video streams.

On Linux you'll be in a bit of trouble.  If you recompile ffmpeg you might get it recording video.  I think recordmydesktop won't do the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Vista the latest version of [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/) might also do what you need. I haven't tried it for that, though, just games

Comment: It seems the WoW community uses that extensively ;)

Comment: Fraps only records DirectX or OpenGL renderings such as games. Probably not best suited for general screencast recording.

Answer (score 0):

DemoCreator could be an good option. It is easy to use, and there are powerful editing features with it.

[http://www.sameshow.com/demo-creator.html](http://www.sameshow.com/demo-creator.html#107)