# Recommendation for screen video capture for demos

Tags: video-capture

I am just in the process of making some little demo tutorial videos for my app to help users get up to speed.  I have used Camtasia in the past but don't really like it.  Anyone have any recommendations.  Good is more important than free, but free certainly helps.

I can use Windows or Mac for this job.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there is a bunch of tools listed [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000721.html) and [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/08/19/screencasting-how-to-start/).

Also, you might want to check on previous threads:

[What’s a good program to record video or screencast being played on screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59525/whats-a-good-program-to-record-video-or-screencast-being-played-on-screen)

[Screencast software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24125/screencast-software)

[Tips on recording a webcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763/tips-on-recording-a-webcast)

Comment: thanks.  One of the weaknesses as I see it of Stack Overflow is that it is quite hard to find stuff because of the breadth of keywords that are used.